# Running Feedly without installing app in browser

Tags: feedly

I have no access to app store (Google Chrome) at work and just wondering is there any way to run feedly as a simple site, like Google Reader used to be.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you cannot for now. Probably Feedly uses some of Chrome's application tools.

Comment: Do you perhaps know why it apparently can't do it now?

Comment: Why? Feedly don't let you, so, like I mention, they probably use some technology only available to Chrome Apps. I suppose storage functionality.

Comment: Feedly uses background services which runs inside Google Chrome, just like Google Chrome which runs inside windows. Hence need permissions to run web apps inside google services.

Comment: Feedly just wants to have a "spy" in your browser, that's it. Maybe extension code is harmless for now, but nobody knows what will be next.